# Application crash when send apk file using bluetooth?

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth

Hello sir i have developing one project so in my project i generate apk file and then after i create URI list and then after send multiple file using bluetooth but when i send file at that time give error  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-17 14:40:12.875: E/AndroidRuntime(2961): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE typ=*/* pkg=com.android.bluetooth (has extras) }

and my send apk Intent code is:

```
   try{
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);

    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.setPackage("com.android.bluetooth");
    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, files);
    MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
    GenerateApk.selectedPackageList.clear();
    listadaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }catch (Exception ex){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),ex.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: this code is working in API level 19 but not working below that what kind of change is require. thanks in advanced :)

Comment: Hello sir anyone has solution for this problem then please give me...

Answer (score 0):

Here it seems you are using explicit intent. And the error code 2961 belongs to memory errors like insufficient memory or probably handle which called by intent is not found in memory.

Here error text associated with 2961 clearly shows that it has a problem with SEND_MULTIPLE. Because while intent wont find associated handler/action in app component it trows such errors.

I just wanted you to take look here and modify your code. 
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Comment: can you give me a very small demo because i try but it not worked.. plz

Comment: any one have any another solution plz post that... thank you in advanced